# Build Process and Powershell - Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, build

I am trying to add a script (possibly a PowerShell script) to my Visual Studio C# project. The goal of this script is to re-create a file every time I build my project. Ideally this script would run before Visual Studio's build process every time I want to build my project.

I am completely new to this process and I don't seem to find a way (or understand) a way of doing this.

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT : This is what my PowerShell script looks like.

```
$file_path = 'C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\TestScripts'
$file_name = 'test.xml'

$file = $file_path +'\'+ $file_name

$file_exist = Test-Path $file

If($file_exist)
{
    Remove-Item $file
}

$file_header_comment = '<!-- This file was auto generated during the build process -->'

New-Item -Path $file_path -Name $file_name -Value $file_header_comment -ItemType file -force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project's properties, on the Build Events tab, invoke your script on the Pre-build event command line. Something like:

```
Powershell.exe -File myScript.ps1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I had a small problem with ExecutionPolicies but it ended up working :)